# extend org-mode unordered list characters

Tags: emacs, org-mode

`org-mode` uses `*` and `+` for unordered list.  I want to be able to use [utf-8 bullet character](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/8226/bullet).  Is there some list that defines this set of characters I can customize?

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the sources [`emacs/lisp/org/org-list.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/org/org-list.el):

```
(defun org-item-re ()
  "Return the correct regular expression for plain lists."
  (let ((term (cond
           ((eq org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator t) "[.)]")
           ((= org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator ?\)) ")")
           ((= org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator ?.) "\\.")
           (t "[.)]")))
    (alpha (if org-list-allow-alphabetical "\\|[A-Za-z]" "")))
    (concat "\\([ \t]*\\([-+]\\|\\(\\([0-9]+" alpha "\\)" term
        "\\)\\)\\|[ \t]+\\*\\)\\([ \t]+\\|$\\)")))
```

appear to indicate a negative answer.

There is no way for you to make this function return a regexp matching • - unless you are willing to edit it.